# Can I overcome the inbuilt JSON length limit during serialisation of a web dataGridView?

Tags: json, gridview, serialization, deserialization

I am getting below error:

> "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.Parameter name: input"

I have a standard ASP.NET application rather than MVC. My application creates a blank `datagrid` with an 25 number of columns (and a 1000 of rows) and user copy/paste1000 records into grid (in fact an Infragistics Web Datagrid -- I am assuming the difference is not significant). The error then occurs during the click on button click:

> Exception information:
>              at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
>              at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(String input)
>              at Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.RunBot.HandleOnInit(HttpContext context)
>              at Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.Data.FlatDataBoundControl.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>              at Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.WebDataGrid.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>              at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I have tried setting `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>` in the **`web.config`** file but this hasn't made a difference, which isn't altogether surprising given that I'm not using a web service. I've also tried the following web.config settings, all to no effect:

```
        <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2147483647"/>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647"/>
        <add key="aspnet:UpdatePanelMaxScriptLength" value="2147483647" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in web.config

```
<system.web.extensions> <scripting> <webServices> <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/> </webServices> </scripting> </system.web.extensions>
```

In code behind

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; 
 YourObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<yourObject>(yourJsonString);
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it is not working. Because I am not using any webService.I have just a simple data grid when trying to click on submit button after copy/paste 1000 records i am getting above error.

Comment: I am thinking you did not get my issue...i am not using any json string ...the issue is happening in inbuild serialization or deserialization of grid data in asp.net.it is not even going to code behind.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow override the internal serialization/deserialization process of a GridView (or equivalent) in order for it to work with arbitrarily large data?

Comment: WebDataGrid uses AjaxFramework to filter data as well as Paging and other behaviors. The maximum length of data that can be sent depends on browser, web server as well as limitation of Ajax Framework on POST request. Grid does partial post back.

In order to work around this limitation you may set EnableAjax property of the WebDataGrid to "False".

Comment: Is it the same exception, in case you are getting timeout exception, this might help http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/25369/92964.aspx&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=434&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1485064681&sig=AF9NedljT3tvhVlvAb1h2p97hspSxy_EJQ

Comment: i have tried with the enableAjax and EnableAjaxViewState property to False..but still getting the exception.

Comment: I am not getting timeout exception..and for safer side I kept _callbackManager.setTimeout(60000);which is 10 min.